# How to set a value with newline by `env` command?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, macos

I mean the use of GNU `env` or BSD `env` command in the form of:

```
env [name=value ...] [utility [args ...]]
```

Looks like there is no way to escape special characters in `value` part but I am not pretty sure how `env` is implemented to parse the `value` part.

I know there are many ways to do this by shell's feature but I want to pass literal string without shell's help (a bit like execute `env` by `exec`). That is to say, I need to find some kind of literal string format with newline and supported by `env` command. For example:

```
env FOO=LITERAL_STRING ruby -e 'puts ENV["FOO"]'
```

Here the `LITERAL_STRING` should contain a literal string with newline and `env` should understand that format.

With the above command, the expected output should be:

```
hello
world
```

I wonder if it is possible. I would appreciate for your help.

**Environment**

- `env`

  I use BSD `env` so it can't print the version. Don't know if `man` can help:

  ```
  $ man env | tail -n1
  BSD                             April 17, 2008                             BSD
  ```
- OS

  ```
  $ sw_vers
  ProductName:    macOS
  ProductVersion: 11.6
  BuildVersion:   20G165
  ```

Comment: What makes you think that `export FOO="hello\nworld"` works any differently than `env BAR="hello\nworld"`?

Comment: What is your actual Q? What is not working when you use env?

Comment: Not on my system. Can you please [edit] your post and add these commands and their output? Also make sure to tell us your operating system and your shell. Oh, and also tell us what output you are expecting. `export FOO="hello\nworld"` shouldn't insert a literal newline.

Comment: Neither on Debian 11.

Comment: But why would you expect `env FOO="hello\nworld"` to add a newline? That isn't how it works. Both `env FOO="hello\nworld" ruby -e 'puts ENV["FOO"]'` and `export FOO="hello\nworld"; ruby -e 'puts ENV["FOO"]'` will print `hello\nworld` and not an actual newline. That is the expected behavior.

Comment: @MarcusMüller oh, sorry, I thought you were the OP. Now I wonder what's different in your system, but never mind :)

Comment: @terdon I figured it out (and will clean up my comments): `zsh` (which is the shell from which I call `export FOO=a\nb; echo $FOO` behaves differently than bash.

Comment: Ah yes, @MarcusMüller, that makes sense. Remember that `echo` is a shell builtin, so it changes between shells and the default behavior of zhs's `echo` is to interpret certain escape sequences, including `\n`. See `man zshbuiltins`, section `echo`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your understanding is incorrect. When you store the content `"hello\nworld"` into a variable, the `\n` is interpreted literally. Only if you invoke tools such as `printf` or `echo` with `-e` flag, they expand those backslash sequences when printing to console.

In your case, you want to pass the variable to the environment with newline character expanded, suggest using the [ANSI C style `$'...'` quoting  operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) of ksh93, now supported by several other shells including bash and zsh for this:

```bash
env FOO=$'hello\nworld' ruby -e 'puts ENV["FOO"]'
```

Or if portability is an issue, a trivial solution is to put those newlines where you want them

```bash
f="hello
world"

env FOO="$f" ruby -e 'puts ENV["FOO"]'
```

Comment: You used one of the shell feature called substitution that would process argements before forking the env process. That's kind of cheating in my opinion.

Comment: Not sure what substitution you are referring to here. I've made an alternate solution too. Also what you mean by cheating in this context? This is how you would do if you wanted an expanded newline character to be present in the variable _before_ passing to your program.

Comment: @WeihangJian the main point is that `var="foo\nbar"` _never_ means "foo, then a newline and then bar". It always means "foo, then a slash, then an `n` and then bar". That's just how it works.

Comment: @WeihangJian, you already determined that `env` itself doesn't interpret backslash escapes or such, so the only way you can pass a newline to it is to pass it as a bare raw newline. To do that from the shell, the simple options are either the `$'...'` or using a hard newline. The intermediate variable is of no consequence, you could use `env FOO='hello<newline>world' cmd...` directly  (with a raw newline in place the `<newline>` placeholder, of course). Please don't accuse people of cheating when they try to provide you with ways to do what you need to do.

Comment: @lnian My environment would execute the env command without spawning a new shell process, that's my the limitation. :( And that why I wonder if the implementation of env can escape nonprintable characters.

Comment: @WeihangJian `env` isn't relevant. Both `env` and `export var` work in _exactly_ the same way. The only thing that could possibly change is how you are testing it since different tools will use `a\nb` differently (e.g.: `/usr/bin/echo 'a\nb'` vs `printf 'a\nb`)  but you haven't shown us an example of both approaches, and you still haven't told us your operating system or your shell, so we can't reproduce what you see to explain it to you.

Comment: @ilkkachu I eventually use some printable encodings like base64 or JSON which is pretty close to your suggestion.

Comment: @WeihangJian Please **[edit]** the question adding what terdon is asking, and any other relevant information. Don't do that in the comments.

Comment: @terdon, Appreciate your feedback, I would improve the question ASAP after home (I am replying on the bus by a smartphone).

Comment: @WeihangJian lol, understandable :) We can wait.

Comment: @terdon Sorry for waiting so long, I have provided more context.

Comment: @WeihangJian Thanks for those updates. BTW, the second example  of my answer should work for you.

Comment: Thank you @Inian. Your second example does solve my issue. <3

Answer (score 5):

[GNU's](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/env-invocation.html) and [FreeBSD's](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?env) `env` have a `-S` ("split") option[1] which splits its argument on spaces and then interprets a lot of escapes in the resulting strings, including but not limited to `\n`:

```
$ env -S 'foo=bar\nquux printenv foo'
bar
quux
$ env -S 'foo=bar\nquux' printenv foo
bar
quux
```

[1] its main use is for `#! ...` shebang lines, but it could be used in other places where a command line is expected, yet an ad-hoc parser rather than a shell is used to interpret it, like the `-e` option of most vte-based terminals.

Answer (score 4):

The `env` command, when executed takes a number of arguments --just like any command-- from the `execve()` system call. The process executing it will do something like:

```
execve("/path/to/env", ["env", "-options", "var=value", "cmd", "arg"], environ);
```

And `env`, in turn, will do (generally in the same process):

```
execve("/path/to/cmd", ["cmd", "arg"], modified_environ);
```

where `modified_environ` is `environ` but with `var=value` appended to it, or if there was already one or more string starting with `var=` in `environ`, the first of them (at least) replaced with `var=value`.

Those arguments are NUL-terminated arrays of bytes, so the only bytes they can't contain is the NUL byte. Same applies to environment variables whose neither name nor value can contain NUL bytes.

`env`, upon startup, processes its arguments from first to last.

The ones at the start that start with `-` would be taken as options.

`-` alone is also treated as the ancient form of `-i` to ignore `environ`.

The ones following options (or `--` that can be used to mark the end of options) that contain at least one `=` will be considered as env var strings (to put in `modified_environ` above). The first non-option argument that doesn't contain a `=` character is considered as the command name (which will be passed as first argument to the command and also used to look-up the path of the executable in `$PATH`).

Any argument after that will be passed as arguments to the command even if they start with `-` or contain `=` characters.

So for `env` itself, only the `-` and `=` characters are special; `-` only during option processing, and `=` only until the command name is found.

To be able to pass an environment variable name that starts with `-` or a command name that starts with `-`, you can just use `--`:

```
execve("/usr/bin/env", ["env", "--", "-var-=value", "cmd"], environ);
```

```
execve("/usr/bin/env", ["env", "--", "-cmd-"], environ);
```

With several `env` implementations, `-` alone following `--` would still not be taken as a command name. So if you wanted to call the command called `-`, you'd need to pass at least one environment variable beforehand:

```
execve("/usr/bin/env", ["env", "--", "dummy=", "-", "args"], environ);
```

(or use `/path/to/-` or `./-` instead of `-` and bypath `$PATH` look up of that `-` command).

`env` however doesn't let you run a command whose name contains `=` characters and can't pass a string without `=` characters in the `modified_environ`. There is no way to escape the `=` character in those cases.

But in your case of `env` `FOO=LITERAL_STRING`, there is no character in `LITERAL_STRING` other than the NUL byte that would be a problem as far as `env` itself is concerned.

Now, when writing code in some language to execute that `env` command, there will likely be characters in that language that can't be entered literally.

For instance, in `perl`, you'd do:

```
exec "env", "--", "-text-=hello\nworld\n", "printenv", "--", "-text-";
```

With the newline character expressed as `\n` inside double quotes, though you could also do:

```
exec qw(env --), q(-text-=hello
world
), qw(printenv -- -text-);
```

To pass strings that contain newline characters.

In the syntax of Bourne-like shell languages, the newline character is not special when inside single or double quotes (like for the `q(...)` or `qq(...)` quoting operators of `perl`), so you could do:

```
exec env -- "-text-=hello
world
" printenv -- -text
```

It would be a different matter in the C shell, or in the rc shell where `"..."` is not a quoting operator.

Your `env FOO=LITERAL_STRING ruby -e 'puts ENV["FOO"]'` looks like code in a shell language. That syntax would be valid with most shells as virtually all understand space as word delimiters, and `'...'` as a quoting operator.

When you omit the `exec` at the start, shells run the command in a child process, and then wait for that process to terminate or be suspended.

If that `env FOO=LITERAL_STRING ruby -e 'puts ENV["FOO"]'` is for a language that doesn't allow entering newline characters literally (likely not a shell) nor using some form of encoding (`\n`, `%0a`, `&#10;`...), but apparently supports `'...'` as a quoting operator like most shells do, beside the BSD `env -S` trick already [suggested by @UncleBilly](/a/673268), you can invoke an interpreter or a language that can execute commands and allows specifying newline some encoded way, such as `perl`, `ruby`, `python`, `ksh93`, `zsh`, `bash`...

Since you already have `ruby`:

```
ruby -e 'exec "env", "FOO=a\n\n\nb", *ARGV' -- ruby -e 'puts ENV["FOO"]'
```

But any descent programming language including `ruby` can set environment variables by themselves, so you don't need `env`:

```
ruby -e 'ENV["FOO"]="a\n\n\nb"; exec *ARGV' -- ruby -e 'puts ENV["FOO"]'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a literal newline in the value:

```bsh
$ env FOO="hello                                  
world" ruby -e 'puts ENV["FOO"]'
```

Output:

```
hello
world
```

If you have a string with `\n` you want to convert to an actual newline, use a utility such as `printf`, just as you would anywhere else:

```bsh
$ env FOO="$(printf "%b" 'hello\nworld')" ruby -e 'puts ENV["FOO"]'
```

```
hello
world
```

`env` isn't special in that respect (in fact, `env` only ever sees the real newline, because it's expanded before the process is started).

Comment: +1 beware though that with `env FOO="$(printf "%b" 'hello\nworld\n\n\n')"`, all the trailing newline characters would be removed by the command substitution. `bash` and `zsh` support `printf -v tmp %b "$string_with_escapes"; env FOO="$tmp" ...` but in `zsh`, you'd rather use `env FOO=${(g::)string ...` (echo-style, though `\c` not handled) or `${(g:o:)string}` (C/usual-style)